# Mp3 file isolated storage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i want to affect the stream that i read forme isolated storage in  Microsoft.FrameWorck.Media.Song i had done this code:

```
  public void Restory()
{
        `  Media.ClearValue(MediaElement.SourceProperty);
          using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = solatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
          {
              if (ISF.FileExists(MainPage.filename))
                  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream FS = ISF.OpenFile(MainPage.filename,FileMode.Open))
                  {

                      this.Media.SetSource(FS);
                      Media.Play();
                  //Media is Mediaenlement But in this step
                     i want to put that stream in Microsoft.Xna.FrameWorck.Media.Song
                  }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. `Song` is only for tracks that are stored in the user's [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx), a remote URI, or in the XAP file itself, but not in isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a tee-stream (splits a stream for 2 consumers) might be useful here, although if reads happen at a differing rate, you're going to consume memory.

[Here's an implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3922/EchoStream-An-Echo-Tee-Stream-for-NET), and [here's another](http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/tee-stream-in-csharp).